# If Loop - Index out of range

Tags: python, loops

this is the code

```
for i in np.arange(len(tupel)):
    if tupel[i][0]+1 == tupel[i+1][0] and tupel[i][1] != 0:
        pre.append((tupel[i][1]))
    else:
        means.append(pre)
        pre = []
```

pre and means are just two lists. I have another list: "tupel". It looks something like

```
[(0, 10), (1, 16), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 11), (9, 18), (10, 4), (11, 0), (12, 0), (13, 0), (14, 0), (15, 0), (16, 0), (17, 0), (18, 12), (19, 16), (20, 1)]
```

All tupels where the 2nd element is zero should be cut off by " != 0" argument. As you can see, the non-zero values  (2nd element) exists in some intervals. Now what I want to do is calculating the mean of the sum of the 2nd elements OF following items.

For e.g.

(0, 10), (1,16) have non-zero 2nd elements. I want the mean the mean of the 1st element and 2nd elements. Would be: (1, 26/2).

(2,0), (3,0) ,(4,0), .. should be cut off. Because the 2nd element is zero.
(8, 11), (9, 18), (10,4) should be: (27/3, 33/3).

To check if the following items where the 2nd element is non-zero are "next integers" i created the loop (code above). But I get the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I check the following item in the list without exceeding the range of the index?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably problem is `[i+1]` - you use `index out of range`. You need `np.arange(len(tupel)-1):`

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `[i+1]` - you use index `out of range`. You need `np.arange(len(tupel)-1)`

Comment: Problem appeared: Now the loop "forgets" the last element of my tupel list.

Comment: you have to add last element manually - there is no special rule to check last element.

Comment: Ah, okay. Didnt know that. Thank you, furas!